# Login by Jsoup is it save?

Tags: java, security, https, save, jsoup

Hello i have a program written in Java useing Jsoup that log me in to specific website.
And what i want to know is if it's save ?
When i use browser the protocol is https.

http://oi47.tinypic.com/aysp4m.jpg

So then if i use my program is it save or someone can steal my password ?

```
        res2 = Jsoup
                .connect("https://bannersbroker.com//user/login?event=doLogin")
                .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17")
                .cookies(res.cookies())
                .data("email", email)
                .data("pass", pass)
                .data(name[0], value[0])
                .data(name[1], value[1])
                .data(name[2], value[2])
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();
```

If it's not save how to secure it ?

Answer (score 0):

This should be as save as *https* is. But you have to make shure nobody can steal your password from from your program (access your `pass` variable, decompile code, read you storage file etc.)

To make sure *https* is working you can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). Trace the networkactivity of your program and see if your data is encrypted.